# startService starts MainActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, service

I am using

```
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class));
```

from `Activity` or `BroadcastReceiver` (using `Context context`). In every situation, service starts, but with that starts `MainActivity` also. How to fix it?
Service code:

```
public class NotificationService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
...
<activity
    android:name=".ViewProfileActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_view_profile"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
</activity>

<service
    android:name=".NotificationService"
    android:process=":NotificationService" >
</service>
...
```

**UPD.** Broadcast receiver:

```
public class BootBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
}
}
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I want to start just service. Without starting MainActivity.
I want to use this it in BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast receiver, but it is not a solution for me to run MainActivity with every device boot. I need to run background service only

Comment: So instead of having an activity in your app, just have the service and broadcast receiver?

Comment: I have activities and service. In broadcast receiver I start service only, but with that by unknown reasons starts MainActivity also.

Comment: Share the code of your broadcast receiver.

Comment: Added to question. But I don't think that the problem is in receiver, because when I use startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationService.class)); from any activity (for example, from ViewProfileActivity or any other) by this command starts service and MainActivity also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MainActivity starts from onCreate of Application class.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this code in your `MainActivity` like this:

```
startForegroundService(Intent(applicationContext, MyService::class.java));
```